# Unable to use nodejs express api with hpoo

Tags: node.js, express

While integrating  express api with hpoo (using  httpClient V1 and V2) ,but its not giving any success

```
app.post('/volume', function(req, res) { 
  var reqBody = req.body;
  var user = reqBody.user;
  var args = user; 
  var exec = require('child_process').exec;

  function puts(error, stdout, stderr) {
    res.send(stdout);
  }

  var cmd ='/abc.sh'+' '+'--apivolcreation'+' '+args;
  exec(cmd,puts); 
});
```

Comment: I am trying to integrate express api with hpoo (via httpClient V1 and V2) ,but its not giving any success.When i run method "post" ,it always failing with "server not respond" error however "get" to the same URL is always ok. When i run with "put" its success but not displaying any result .

Comment: show us some code please

Comment: app.post('/volume', function(req, res)
                {
var reqBody = req.body;
var user = reqBody.user;
var args = user ;
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
function puts(error, stdout, stderr) {
res.send(stdout);
}
var cmd ='/abc.sh'+' '+'--apivolcreation'+' '+args;
                        exec(cmd,puts);
                });

Comment: Why not just use the request module against the rest API instead?

Comment: This is solved with a token based autheization .thank you